# Does Linq Contains() check for HashSet?

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

Sometimes a HashSet is exposed through a property as an IEnumerable.

It is well known that for `enumerable.Count()` the code checks if it is a collection, so it doesn't enumerate the whole list, but takes a shortcut.

Is there any similar check for using the Linq version of `enumerable.Contains(x)` and HashSets?

Comment: The shortcut for `Count()` is a property. How would a property properly return a boolean for a dynamic expression?

Comment: why don't you look at yourself: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: what do you mean exactly?....if calling contains(x) in a query will only check part of the list?

Comment: @TravisJ He means that `Enumerable.Count()` checks to see if the object is of type `ICollection` and if so returns `ICollection.Count` as an optimization.  If it's not it has to enumerate the enumerable in order to count the items.

Comment: @cdhowie - Yes I understood that aspect, but how does that relate to `Contains`?

Comment: It appears that at least [Mono does do this](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs#L605).  (Set types should implement `ICollection`, and so this would call the set's implementation of `ICollection.Contains()`.)  I would not be surprised if MS.NET did this too.

Comment: @TravisJ `ICollection` also has a `Contains` method that can implement specialized logic, for example in the case of a `HashSet<T>` it can perform the test in average O(1) time, versus enumerating the elements until a match is found.

Comment: I wouldn't think it does that because HashSet is a collection of unique objects, so it needs to know what objects already exist in the collection.  I would think that Contains would check the map of already inserted objects.  Best bet is to check the reference source.

Comment: @MauriceReeves I can't make heads or tails of your statements.

Comment: It's alright, per the answer below, my supposition was wrong.  What I was trying to say was that HashSet is a collection of unique objects, so I would have guessed that HashSet had overloaded Contains and not used the method from ICollection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), yes it does, though not directly:

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value) {
    ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collection != null) return collection.Contains(value);
    return Contains<TSource>(source, value, null);
}
```

If the source enumerable implements [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx) (and [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) does), then it uses the collection's [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: +1 but I would point out that it *does not* check for `HashSet<T>` *specifically* (as that is the question that was asked) but that it will check for `ICollection<T>`, and therefore accomplish the same thing without needing to have specialized knowledge of `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Note also it is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.90).aspx) to look for `ICollection<T>` (see *Remarks*).