# How can I create a constant hashset in c#

Tags: c#, hashset

Right now I have a const array of strings and loop through to check if a value exists. But I want a more efficient way to store my values. I know there's a hashset which I can use like so:

```
HashSet<string> tblNames = new HashSet<string> ();
tblNames.Add("a");
tblNames.Add("b");
tblNames.Add("c");
```

However, is it possible to make this a constant member of my class like this:

```
public const HashSet<string> tblNames = new HashSet<string>() { "value1", "value2" };
```

Comment: `But I want a more efficient way to store my values.` What do you mean by `more efficient`?

Comment: I'd suggest using `static readonly` rather than `const`. Alas, since it is `public` other code will be able to add or remove items from the `HashSet`.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think this is necessarily a duplicate of the `const` questions, as they don't address preventing the Set contents from being added/removed.

Comment: The OP probably wants an immutable `HashSet<T>`. There is an [`ImmutableHashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablehashset-1) class in the package [System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way to create a 'constant' Set is probably by exposing your `HashSet` as its `IEnumerable` interface, using the following:

```
public static readonly IEnumerable<string> fruits = new HashSet<string> { "Apples", "Oranges" };
```

- `public`: everyone can access it.
- `static`: there's only going to be one copy in memory, no matter how many instances of the parent class is created.
- `readonly`: you can't re-assign it to a new value.
- `IEnumerable<>`: you can only iterate through its contents, but not add/remove/modify.

To search, you can use LINQ to call `Contains()` on your `IEnumerable`, and it is smart enough to know it's backed by a `HashSet` and delegate the proper call to utilise the hashed nature of your set. (well, ok, [it calls it via ICollection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275107), but ends up in HashSet's overridden method anyway)

```
Debug.WriteLine(fruits.Contains("Apples")); // True
Debug.WriteLine(fruits.Contains("Berries")); // False

fruits = new HashSet<string>(); // FAIL! readonly fields can't be re-assigned
fruits.Add("Grapes"); // FAIL! IEnumerables don't have Add()
```

Comment: I am curious why a const field can't be marked as static but a readonly value can

Comment: From the C# language spec: [A constant or type declaration is implicitly a static member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Comment: This is not constant it's readonly. Therefore useless when the expression must be constant. Would be more useful to investigate whether or not it is possible to create a constant hash table in C#.

Comment: Just to clarify on this 

`and it is smart enough to know it's backed by a HashSet and delegate the proper call to utilise the hashed nature of your set. (well, ok, it calls it via ICollection, but ends up in HashSet's overridden method anyway)`

IEnumerable and ICollection are simply interfaces. They do not define default implementations for `Contains()`. When you call `Contains()` it will directly call the hashset implementation.